# What is the ? in ?char

Tags: ruby

I do not understand the `?` in `?x.succ`.  What is it?

(This question was prompted by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42438) on code golf.)

Comment: Context is important. Generally, you'd just do "x" or something similar for clarity. `?x` is just a "golfy" way to write "x"

Comment: @Brennan Yeah, ?x is a character less than "x", which explains why it might be used in the code golf setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just means "character", as in `?x` is "x character". This was a bigger deal in versions of Ruby prior to 1.9. Now it's mostly an anachronism.

Ruby 1.9+:

```
?x
# => "x"
```

Ruby 1.8.7 and prior:

```
?x
# => 120
```

This was similar to how `'x'` in C is a single character where `"x"` is a character string.

Comment: That explains why it only works with a single character.  Why was it changed with ruby 1.9? Also, how should I refer to it? It seems more like a syntax thing than an operator, so I could understand if it doesn't exactly have a name, but googling ? hasn't exactly gotten me very far...

Comment: @user3334690 Personally, I'd just call it a "character literal".

Comment: I believe it was an efficiency concession in earlier versions of Ruby which, you must remember, date back to the mid 1990s when computers were orders of mangitude slower. The overhead of creating a string to represent a single character was too high for some tasks. Now it's a non-issue, hence the switch.

Comment: Strings in Ruby prior to 1.9 were basically just byte arrays. This worked well if you just had ASCII text but fell over once you had to deal with unicode. In Ruby 1.9 and up, strings consist of characters (which can be multiple bytes when serialized, thus not to be confused with C `chars` which are just single byte). Thus, it's rare to create a single character string that way, as Strings are way more complex anyway.

Comment: @HolgerJust Great point about UTF-8 implications. I've been trying to forget what a painful transition that was.